# How can I decrypt a Kerberos ticket in perl

Tags: perl, kerberos

As part of a larger project I'm receiving Kerberos tickets embedded in some XML and need to decide if they are valid for the ktab on the server.

I have been looking into ['Authen::Krb5'](https://metacpan.org/module/Authen%3a%3aKrb5) and ['Authen::Krb5::Simple'](https://metacpan.org/module/Authen%3a%3aKrb5%3a%3aSimple) though I'm not finding any examples of using these to decrypt a ticket.

Is `Authen::Krb5` a reasonable solution? Are there any examples available?

Answer (score 4):

```
 # simple_server
 # uses rd_req & rd_priv to decrypt an authentic encrypted message

 use blib;
 use IO::Socket;
 use Sys::Hostname;
 use Authen::Krb5 (ADDRTYPE_INET,ADDRTYPE_IPPORT,KRB5_NT_SRV_HST);

 # replace with your own stuff
 $SERVICE = "sample";
 $KEYTAB_FILE = "/etc/krb5.keytab";

 chomp($SERVER = hostname());

 Authen::Krb5::init_context();
 Authen::Krb5::init_ets();

 $ac = new Authen::Krb5::AuthContext;

 $s = new IO::Socket::INET(
         LocalAddr => $SERVER,
         LocalPort => 12345,
         Proto => 'tcp',
         Reuse => 1,
         Listen => 5
 );
 defined $s or die $!;

 $ns = $s->accept();

 # grab the client's address
 $addr = new Authen::Krb5::Address(ADDRTYPE_INET,pack("N",$ns->peeraddr()));
 $ports = new Authen::Krb5::Address(ADDRTYPE_IPPORT,pack("n",$ns->peerport()));

 # get authentication info
 while (defined($line = <$ns>)) {
         $d .= $line;
         if ($line =~ /__END$/) {
                 chomp $d;
                 $d =~ s/__END$//;
                 last;
         }
 }

 # get encrypted message
 while (defined($line = <$ns>)) {
         $enc .= $line;
         if ($line =~ /__END$/) {
                 chomp $enc;
                 $enc =~ s/__END$//;
                 last;
         }
 }

 $sprinc = Authen::Krb5::sname_to_principal($SERVER,$SERVICE,KRB5_NT_SRV_HST);
 $kt = Authen::Krb5::kt_resolve("FILE:$KEYTAB_FILE");
 $t = Authen::Krb5::rd_req($ac,$d,$sprinc,$kt);
 unless ($t) {
         print "rd_req error: ",Authen::Krb5::error(),"\n";
         exit(1);
 }

 $client = $t->enc_part2->client;
 print "Hello, ",$client->data,"\n";

 # set the remote address
 $ac->setaddrs(undef,$addr);
 $ac->setports(undef,$ports);

 # decrypt the message
 $dec = Authen::Krb5::rd_priv($ac,$enc);
 unless ($dec) {
         print "rd_priv error: ",Authen::Krb5::error(),"\n";
         exit(1);
 }

 print "Decrypted message is: '$dec'\n";

 Authen::Krb5::free_context();
```